# How can I make a makefile to test some inputs?

Tags: c++, makefile

So I have this C++ program and I have some inputs for it that I need to test.

I need to do a makefile for it to test them all, but I dont have the slightest clue how to do it, or what I need to write in my C++ program to get the inputs from the makefile.

I know the basics of makefiles, like the build, valgrind and clear commands, but this I dont have a clue how I can make....
I also need to create some .out files with the output of my program.

I know this might be a stupid and easy question, but I dont find the answer to both my questions(How can I make this makefile work and how I can parse the files from the makefile into my C program).
EDIT:
So this is how my makefile looks now. Now, how can I run them all at once? Can I do this?

`Tarjan: g++ Tarjan.cpp -Wall -o Tarjan`

`run_test1: ./Tarjan input/input_test1.in output/output_test1.out`

`run_test2: ./Tarjan input/input_test2.in output/output_test2.out`

`run_test3: ./Tarjan input/input_test3.in output/output_test3.out`

`run_test4: ./Tarjan input/input_test4.in output/output_test4.out`

`run_test5: ./Tarjan input/input_test5.in output/output_test5.out`

`run_test6: ./Tarjan input/input_test6.in output/output_test6.out`

`run_test7: ./Tarjan input/input_test7.in output/output_test7.out`

`run_test8: ./Tarjan input/input_test8.in output/output_test8.out`

`run_test9: ./Tarjan input/input_test9.in output/output_test9.out`

`run_test10: ./Tarjan input/input_test10.in output/output_test10.out`

`clean: rm Tarjan rm output/output*.out`

Comment: `make` runs executables as these are defined in the rules in the `makefile`, so you can also run the executable build with the makefile for testing. Input can be given from files, either by I/O redirection in case your program reads from standard input, or by specifying the filename as parameter if the program takes it. Dependencies in the rule should be the executable artifact, or the files containing the testdata. You don't need to know anything about the `makefile` in your program.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what where you trying to say, but I think you meant that I can use the argv[] in C/C++. I found this a lot easier, to have the input file in argv[1] and the output in argv[2]

Comment: Well, usually the "easier" way is to use shell I/O redirection, if your program already takes input via `std::cin` and writes output to `std::cout`. If you didn't write your program yet, you can design it to use the command line arguments to specify the input / output files.

Comment: I wrote it already with argv[], and it works preety nice with the Makefile, but I dont know how I can run multiple tests yet :(

Comment: Create multiple make targets, one for each test, see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping it as simple as possible, sounds like you'll need a `Makefile` similar to:

```
my_app: <tab> my_app.cpp
  <tab> g++ -Wall -g -o my_app my_app.cpp
  <tab> ./my_app < my_test_input
```

Then you can create a file called `my_test_input` with whatever your test input is, and read it from the standard input of the `./my_app` process:

```
int an_int;
std::string a_space_separated_word;

if (std::cin >> an_int >> a_space_separated_word)
    // do something with the inputs...
else {
    std::cerr << "failed to read inputs\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

std::string line;
while (getline(std::cin, line))
{
    ...get all the lines in the input into line, one by one...
}
```

Comment: I'd rather put the testing stuff into separate make rules. The `all` target could use these as dependencies.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I'd do that for myself too, but I figured simple-as-possible was best for someone who just needs to get started....

Comment: As I can see it, this runs only a test. I need to run multiple tests, but I saw somewhere that I can do something lije `tests: test1, test2, test3,....` and then `./my_app < tests`.Is this ok? And this approach makes different runs of the executable? Because I have some structures that will need overwriting if I dont run multiple instances of this program.

Comment: @Mihai93 _"... I need to run multiple tests ..."_ Create a separate make rule for each test. The only parameters changing in these rules are the names of the input / output files. `./my_app < tests` won't do what you want. The rule `tests: test1, test2, test3` would just define the dependencies for the single test targets `test1` etc.

Comment: I did this, but can I run them all at once? I updated my original post

Comment: @Mihai93 You can run multiple tests by adding appending extra lines to the Makefile content I list in my answer, e.g. ` <tab> ./my_app < some_other_test_input > save_the_test_output`.  Alternatively, you can retain the ability to run individual tests, OR run them all, but adding a target like (using the target names appended to the Q) `tests: run_test1 run_test2 run_test3...` - on the next line, just put a dummy build step like `<tab> echo "running all tests"`.  When you type `make tests` it will see `tests` depends on first running all those other build steps.